# spring data jpa: Insert instead of delete

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, junit4

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file. I have created this Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface MenuRepository extends CrudRepository<Menu, Long> {

      @Cacheable("menus")
      @Query("select cur from Menu cur where cur.MenuId = ?1")
      Menu findMenuByMenuId (String MenuId);

      @Cacheable("menus")
      @Query("select cur from Menu cur where lower (cur.symbol) = lower (?1) ")
      Menu findMenuBySymbol (String symbol);
```

and this service:

```
@Service
public class MenuService {

        @Autowired
    protected MenuRepository menuRepository;    

    @Autowired
    MenuPriceService menuPriceService;


     @Transactional
     public Menu save (Menu menu) {              
         return menuRepository.save (menu);
     }


     @Transactional
     public void delete (Menu menu) {
         menuRepository.delete  (menu);
     }
     ..
}


}
```

and this JUNIT test:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testDelete () {

        String menuName = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";

        Menu menu = new Menu(); 
        menu.setMenuId(menuName);
        menuService.delete (menu);
}
```

but this is what I see in the console

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        t_menu
        (...) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While removing `@Transactional` [as suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885662/66686) might make the behavior go away, I'd question the validity of the test.

The question really is: why do you try to delete an entity that is not in the database?

#### Solution:

If you simulate the case where don't know if the entity exists, use `deleteById` it will throw an exception when the id is not present in the database and you can, of course, catch that.

#### Some background to how and why this insert happens:

`delete(T entity)` is implemented through [`SimpleJpaRepository.delete(T entity)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L158) which basically contains this single line of code.

```
em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
```

As you can see it does a `merge` on the entity if the entity isn't present in the `EntityManager`. Without the `merge` you'd might end up with duplicate entities in the session if another instance with same class and Id does exist in the `EntityManager`. But since your entity doesn't exist at all this triggers an insert into the database.

You might think it as this: You create an instance, you make the `EntityManager` know about it (by telling it to delete it) and you delete it, so these are the steps that need to occur in the database -> insert + delete.

Answer (score 0):

remove `@Transactional`:

```
@Test
    public void testDelete () {

        String menuName = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";

        Menu menu = new Menu(); 
        menu.setMenuId(menuName);
        menuService.delete (menu);
}
```